# Jquery find and show next table

Tags: jquery

I need to create a navigation between tables on my page. I would like to create something like "Table Slider" (Previous Table and Next Table). On this page I have also menu with this script:

```
$("#1").click(function(){          //one of menu button
    $("#content table").hide('fast');  //first table with content
    $('#a').show('fast');             //second table with content
});
```

I think, that the next(); will be work here, all tables are in one div.

This is my structure of all tables:

```
<table id="a" style="display: none">
    <tr>
    <td class="previous">Previous</td>
    <td class="next">Next</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="name"><img class="logo" src="logo.jpg"></img><h1></h1></td>
    <td>Some Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should post the whole html structure.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - not true.. tbody is required only if thead and tfoot is defined

Comment: My bad, it's when creating table with JS in IE that you need to append the `tbody`. HTML automatically create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they're siblings, you can use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) as you mentioned.

We can also delegate this event so that it applies to all your tables within the `#content` div, otherwise you'd have to have a `click` event for each of the tables, which is **not** ideal.

```
$("#content table").on("click", function() {
    $("#content table").hide('fast');
    $(this).next("table").show('fast'); 
});
```

Comment: adding to this solution, you can add function to capture the type of transition, either `Previous` or `Next()` and depending on that you can call `.next()` (to point to next table) and `.previous()`(to point to the previous table). for detecting the end of the row, you may add a extra attribute to the table on the extreme ends.

Comment: It works great, but it is possible, to exclude the images? Now when I click on pictures in table I go to next table.

Comment: @KacperRykis Yeah you'd have to have a click event on the images, something like `$("#content table img").on("click", function () { return false; });`